# Org Beamer Presentation: blocks do not work?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, beamer

I'm using Emacs 25.1 and the most recent orgmode. My problem is that I tried compiling one of the examples on Worg, but the content that's supposed to be displayed in a block is displayed on its own slide:

```
#+STARTUP: beamer
#+TITLE:     Writing Beamer presentations in org-mode
#+AUTHOR:    Eric S Fraga
#+EMAIL:     e.fraga@ucl.ac.uk
#+DATE:      2010-03-30 Tue
#+DESCRIPTION: 
#+KEYWORDS: 
#+LANGUAGE:  en
#+OPTIONS:   H:3 num:t toc:t \n:nil @:t ::t |:t ^:t -:t f:t *:t <:t
#+OPTIONS:   TeX:t LaTeX:t skip:nil d:nil todo:t pri:nil tags:not-in-toc
#+INFOJS_OPT: view:nil toc:nil ltoc:t mouse:underline buttons:0 path:http://orgmode.org/org-info.js
#+COLUMNS: %40ITEM %10BEAMER_env(Env) %9BEAMER_envargs(Env Args) %4BEAMER_col(Col) %10BEAMER_extra(Extra)
#+BEAMER_FRAME_LEVEL: 2
#+EXPORT_SELECT_TAGS: export
#+EXPORT_EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexport
#+LINK_UP:   
#+LINK_HOME:

* A Presentation
** A more complex slide
This slide illustrates the use of Beamer blocks.  The following text,
with its own headline, is displayed in a block:
*** Org mode increases productivity               :B_theorem:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_env: theorem
    :END:
    - org mode means not having to remember LaTeX commands.
    - it is based on ascii text which is inherently portable.
    - Emacs!

    \hfill \(\qed\)
```

Did I miss something? Or is the example simply outdated, and I have to do something else?

Answer (score 6):

Please change `#+options: H:3` to `#+options: H:2`.

This is working for me with Emacs 25.1, Org 9.0.4.
Maybe `#+beamer_frame_level:` became obsolete in Org9, the example is from 2010!